# How to graph three categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, data-visualization

Let's say I have the following data, there are three variables, all categorical. How can you graph this?

```
Bears     Male       Apathetic
Bears     Female     Nice
Wolves    Male       Nice
Wolves    Female     Mean
Badgers   Male       Mean
Badgers   Female     Apathetic
```

The only way I know is by using a heat map that's categorically colored, not colored on a spectrum (side question, is there a better name for that kind of graph?)

Like so:

[image]

[Here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/heat-map-chart/introduction.html) and the image below are a better example of the sort of graph I'm talking about:

[image]

Which is essentially a glorified comparison table:

[image]

I know people often talk about [Mosaic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot) when talking about multivariate categorical data, but those are still numerical, they just count the number of instances of combinations.

Are there any ways of displaying this information other than those I've mentioned?

Comment: What information do you want your graph to convey? Usually, people have counts of the different combinations & the graph informs the viewer of the independence (or lack thereof) of the variables. That's why people recommend mosaic plots. If you want to convey something else, you need to state what it is.

Comment: It would graphically serve as a sort of lookup table, comparing the various combinations. You can also see overall trends for categories. For example in the image I linked, you can easily see WholeSale Trade is very low opportunity, whereas Government is very hot opportunity. I also frequently see similar datasets when companies are comparing their products to their competitors, [like this one here](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/174448-thumb/Apple-Watch-vs-Android-Wear-vs-Pebble-Time-features-software-table.png).